# Is there any generics type that implements QueryInterface?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

Consider the follow code:

```
TMyList = class(TList<IMyItem>, IMyList)
```

Delphi shows me the error:

```
[DCC Error] test.pas(104): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'QueryInterface'
```

Is there a generic list that implements `IInterface`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classes in `Generics.Collections` do not implement `IInterface`. You will have to introduce it yourself in your derived classes and provide the standard implementations. Or find a different, third party, set of container classes to work with.

For example:

```
TInterfacedList<T> = class(TList<T>, IInterface)
protected
  FRefCount: Integer;
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
  function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
  function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
end;

function TInterfacedList<T>.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TInterfacedList<T>._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;

function TInterfacedList<T>._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;
```

You can then declare your specialised class:

```
TMyList = class(TInterfacedList<IMyItem>, IMyList)
```

Remember that you need to treat this class like any other that uses reference counted lifetime management. Only refer to it through interfaces.

You'd really want to do some more work before `TInterfacedList<T>` was useful. You'd need to declare an `IList<T>` which would expose the list capabilities. It would be something like this:

```
IList<T> = interface
  function Add(const Value: T): Integer;
  procedure Insert(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
  .... etc. etc.
end;
```

You can then simply add `IList<T>` to the list of interfaces supported by `TInterfacedList<T>` and the base class `TList<T>` would fulfil the interface contract.

```
TInterfacedList<T> = class(TList<T>, IInterface, IList<T>)
```

Comment: Is it safe to copy the TInterfaceObject's methods?

Comment: I've fleshed the answer out a little. It's not much work to get a pretty capable `IList<T>` based on `TList<T>`.

Comment: Wonderful stuff David! Mason's answer provides some working links, but it's the know-your-underlying-platform answers that really teach and inform most.  +1

Comment: Remember that a guid on a generic interface means that this interface has the same guid for any type of T meaning that supports(myFooList, IList<TBar>) would return true

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for that. To get around that I suppose I need to declare a new type for each specialised IList and add a GUID to each of those specialized interfaces?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No you cannot - see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to my comment above here some explanation why generic interfaces in Delphi don't work with guids.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;


type
  IList<T> = interface
    ['{41FA0759-9BE4-49D7-B3DD-162CAA39CEC9}']
  end;

  IList_String1 = IList<string>;

  IList_String2 = interface(IList<string>)
    ['{FE0CB7A6-FC63-4748-B436-36C07D501B7B}']
  end;

  TList<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IList<T>)
  end;

var
  list: TList<string>;
  guid: TGUID;
begin
  list := TList<string>.Create;

  guid := IList<Integer>;
  Writeln('IList<Integer> = ', guid.ToString);
  if Supports(list, IList<Integer>) then
    Writeln('FAIL #1');

  guid := IList_String1;
  Writeln('IList_String1 = ', guid.ToString);
  if not Supports(list, IList_String1) then
    Writeln('FAIL #2');

  guid := IList_String2;
  Writeln('IList_String2 = ', guid.ToString);
  if not Supports(list, IList_String2) then
    Writeln('FAIL #3');

  Readln;
end.
```

You see that it writes out the same guid for IList and for IList_String1 as IList got this guid and both are from this type. This results in Fail #1 because T does not matter when doing the supports call. Defining an alias for IList works (no Fail #2) but does not help because that still is the same guid. So what we need is what has been done with IList_String2. But that interface is **not** implemented by TList so of course we get Fail #3.

This has been reported long ago: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78458 [[WayBack archived link]](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221084321/qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx%3Fd=78458)

Comment: Is there any way to workaround this avoiding GUIDs and Supports?

Comment: It depends. In Spring we decided to not put guids on the generic interfaces but most of the collection related interfaces (like IList<T>) have a non generic interface which works with TValue. Also IEnumerable (which is the base type of all other collection related interfaces) has a property called ElementType which gives you the typeinfo of T.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I have heard about spring and I was wondering what framework do you guys use to mock objects on your unit tests. I have not found a good mock framework for delphi.

Comment: @RafaelColucci: Actually the mocks are handwritten but there are currently 2 mocking "frameworks" for the most recent Delphi versions (https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/Delphi-Mocks and my own implementation in DSharp: http://delphisorcery.blogspot.de/2011/09/pimp-your-unit-tests-using-mock-objects.html)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Alex Ciobanu's [Collections](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/) library.  It's got a bunch of generic collections, including replacements for the `Generics.Collections` types, that are usable as interfaces.  (They were done that way to facilitate the LINQ-style Enex behavior he set up.)

Comment: I wish I could accept more than 1 answer. Great tools you provided. +1

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to create a wrapper that inherits from `TInterfacedObject` and use composition and delegation for the list functionality:

```
interface
type
  IList<T> = interface<IEnumerable<T>)
    function Add(const Value: T): Integer;
    ..
  end;

TList<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IList<T>)
private
  FList: Generics.Collections.TList<T>;
public
  function Add(const Value:T): Integer;
  ..
end;

implementation
function TList<T>.Add(const Value:T): Integer;
begin
  Exit(FList.Add(Value));
end;
```

Wrapping `TList<T>` and `TDictionary<T>` takes a little over 500 lines of code.

One caveat... I didn't include it here but I created an `IEnumerable<T>` (as well as the related `IEnumerator<T>`) that **does not** descend from `IEnumerable` . Most third party and OSS collection libraries do the same. If you're interested in why [this](http://talkdelphi.blogspot.com/2009/03/implementing-ienumerable-is-nightmare.html) blogpost pretty much sums it up.

Well, actually it doesn't mention everything. Even if you work around the interfaces stepping on each other you'll still have problems. An otherwise perfect implementation that satisfies both interfaces will succeed if you do Build but continue to fail with the same error message if you do an incremental compile (at least in D2009). Also the nongeneric IEnumerator forces you to return the current item as a `TObject`. This pretty much prevents you from holding anything in a collection that can't be cast to `TObject`. That's why none of the *standard* generic collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: This way creates vastly more work than deriving from TList<T>.

Comment: So does implementing your own from scratch, which is what all those third party collections do. It all depends of what you need. If you need a reference counted collection with list semantics but you want to limit how caller's can interact with the collection, wrapping `TList<T>` may be preferable. I never said it was a better solution, just an alternative.